# Using putsUSART and putrsUSART vs printf

Tags: printf, microchip, usart

I am developing an embedded application that can send data to a WCF Service trough a local network. This is achieved by having a PIC18F45K50 send data to a RN-171 module trough USART. The module is connected to the local AP and configured to send the data to my local server that has the WCF service running.
In order to determine the exact string I need to send in other to do that I used Fiddler to spy on the data sent from a client to the service then I copied the whole message and sent it from my micro-controller.

My Problem:
If I send the exact package using printf the server accepts the input and returns an 200 OK and I can find the  test message stored on my computer. 
However I have noticed a really strange problem when trying to use putsUART()

The following code Works:

```
            printf("POST http://grossen-pc:60312/MicroControllerComSvc.svc HTTP/1.1\r\nContent-Type: text/xml;"
                    " charset=utf-8\r\nSOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IMicroControllerComSvc/GetMicrocontrollerData\"\r\nHost: "
                    "192.168.0.104:60312\r\nContent-Length: 245\r\nExpect: 100-continue\r\nAccept-Encoding:"
                    " gzip, deflate\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n<s:Envelope xmlns:s="
                    "\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><s:Body><GetMicrocontrollerData xmlns="
                    "\"http://tempuri.org/\"><microControllerData>");
            printf("%d,%02d,%d,%d,%d,%04d,%02d,%03d,%02d,%02d,%d",PackageType,Device,ID,Data1,State,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data5,Data6,Data7);
            printf("</microControllerData></GetMicrocontrollerData></s:Body></s:Envelope>");
```

If I replace the second printf with:

```
    puts1USART(DataBuffer);
```

The server does not accept the package. DataBuffer is a char array containing the exact same parameters and has the exact same length as the string I used in the printf Instruction.
The same thing happens if for example I want to store the strings in a constant rom char array and I use putrsUSART(); to send them.

I used TeraTerm to view the contents of the package when sending it trough both methods and they seem identical. I am a complete loss why this is happening.

What is the difference between sending data with printf and putsUSART?(except the obvious) 
What could the second function do to the way the string is sent that the server does not like?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the putsUSART/putrsUSART routines. Presumably they are part of some implementation-specific library.

It could be a character pacing issue. You should check with an oscilloscope to see if the characters are being sent at the same rate (I'm not talking about the baud rate, but possible delays between characters).

Comment: In that case I can use the set flush time option the RN-171 has, It will store all the serial data in a internal buffer and send it all out when no more data is received for the selected flush time. I will try that out when I will get the occasion.